# Pixel not on the right page?

Tags: assembly, x86, nasm

I am working on practicing NASM x86, and I am trying to but a pixel (red) on the screen. I try the following code:

```
BITS 16 ;16 bit mode FTW

start: ;define our entry point
    mov     ax,     07C0h
    add     ax,     288
    mov     ss,     ax ;set the stack segment
    mov     ax,     07C0h
    mov     ds,     ax ; set the data segment (code base)
    ;these lines will almost always be the same
    ; mov esi, my_var
    ; call getline
    ; jmp $
    mov cx,100 ; align X
    mov bx,100 ; align Y
    call red_dot
.done:
    ret
red_dot:
     mov ah, 0Ch
     mov al, 00h
     mov bh, 00h
     int 10h
     ret
```

It compiles fine with the following script [batch]:

```
nasm.exe -f bin -o TestOS.bin TestOS.asm
copy /b TestOS.bin TestOS.flp
copy TestOS.flp cdiso
mkisofs.exe -no-emul-boot -boot-load-size 4 -o TestOS.iso -b TestOS.flp cdiso/
```

When I run it in VirtualBox, I get an undercscore aligned at [0,0] , and no red dot?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The y coordinate should be in the `dx` register:

```
mov cx,100 ; align X
mov dx,100 ; align Y
call red_dot
```

Color 0 would be the background color, so use some other color:

```
red_dot:
  mov ah, 0Ch
  mov al, 04h ;red
  mov bh, 00h ;page
  int 10h
  ret
```

But first you need to set a graphics mode where you can actually draw pixels. Example:

```
mov ah, 00h
mov al, 13h ;320x200, 256 colors
int 10h
```

Answer (score 0):

To set a pixel with "int 10h" is very slow. The faster way is to write the color of the pixel directly to the framebuffer. The Segment-Address for the graphic mode 13h is 0A000h. For to calculate the offset address for a pixel= (Y_position * vertical resolution) + X_position

```
mov ax,13h
int 10h       ; set the graphic mode 13h with 320x200, 256 colors

mov ax,0A000h
mov es,ax     ; move the offset address of the framebuffer to the ES-segmentregister

mov cx,100    ; X_position
mov bx,100    ; Y_position (do not need to use another register on this way)

mov ax,200    ; vertical resolution of mode 13h
mul bx        ; * Y_position
add ax,cx     ; + X_position

mov di,ax     ; move the result to an address-register
mov al,color
stosb         ; set the pixel-color in AL to the framebuffer ("mov es:[di],al")
```

Dirk